# Are NOR FLASH NVM ICs generic and largely interchangeable?

Tags: integrated-circuit, firmware, rom

I need a NOR FLASH ROM chip that's SOIC-8 and 16MiB in size, and it's purpose is to contain boot firmware. There are so many that I'm afraid of installing the wrong one to find out it's not suitable for some reason. Are they generic enough that it would be safe to buy any that meet the above criteria? and are there certain brands that are more reliable than others?

I've found [this one](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/winbond-electronics/W25Q128JVSIM/6819721), but like I say I'm unsure it's suitable. If anyone can recommend something I'd be grateful.

Comment: Direct product recommendation requests are off topic here. If you provide information about the used MCU, the interface speed and suggest an IC example, the question can be answered.

Comment: @Jens although, yes, I did say recommendations would be well received, it's not the essence of the question. What I'm asking is whether any FLASH ROM of the same memory type, form factor and capacity will do, or is there more I need to consider? I'm afraid I don't know the Microcontroller of the interface speed.